# MySql select aggregate inside duplicate key while referencing values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: table1 and table2, each of them having 3 fields: (a, b, c) and (x, y, z) all integers (besides let's say another PK field each. that part is not important).

I want to be able to insert multiple rows from table2 into table1 and when a duplicate key is encountered to update the line from table 1 with the original key and set the value of a some fields equal to various functions involving relating to values that would have been inserted in absence of a duplicate key event.

More specifically, this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, a, b, c) 
    SELECT 1, x, SUM(y), COUNT(z) -- for my example to happen, 1 is the duplicate key
    FROM table2 
    GROUP BY x
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    b = b + VALUES(b),
    c = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x) 
             FROM table2 t2
             WHERE VALUES(a) = t2.x);
```

I ran some tests, and on duplicate key the 'b' field is updated correctly, but the c field is being reset to 0. The problem I think is trying to reference `VALUES(a)` (the value that should have been inserted in the 'a' field before 'duplicate key' event happened) further down the stack inside another select.
If I modify the query and remove the last line `WHERE VALUES(a) = t2.x` the answer is the expected one.